# How to get specific value of json data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object, and I want to get the specific value from each key like `fetch_array` in mysql. This is my json:

```
var jsonData = [{"Id":"1","Name":"Ariel"},
                {"Id":"2","Name":"Rick"}];
```

Then I want to loop them in a `<select>` tag with `$.each` function

```
<select>
<option value='//this should be Id key' >//this should be Name key </option>
</select>
```

How do I pass id into the `value` attribute and pass the name in the `<option>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not JSON, it's a javascript array containing objects, and you'd iterate as usual

```
var select = document.querySelector('select');

for (var i=0; i<jsonData.length; i++) {
    var option       = document.createElement('option');
    option.value     = jsonData[i].Id;
    option.innerHTML = jsonData[i].Name;

    select.appendChild(option)
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeg5t/)

Comment: `option.innerHTML == option.text` ??

Comment: @Pilot - Both are supported in all major browsers, innerHTML is usually faster than the text methods, but it wouldn't really matter in this case, both would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, loop and create your options, then append:

```
var options = "";
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    options += "<option value=" + jsonData[i].Id + ">" + jsonData[i].Name + "</option>";
}
$("#IDofSelect").append(options);
```